# third party cookies trackers

Tags: cookies

I have a question regarding how third party cookies track user browsing habits. If the cookie from an advertiser is loaded in an iframe, when we browse websites, only the cookie for the advertiser will be sent to the advertiser. If an iframe from a different domain can't access the DOM for the webpage, how did the advertiser know which page we were on ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) will tell the 3rd party the page that contains the iframe. Also, they may pass information via the URL of the iframe.